# How to implement "continue=false" in Xpages events

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotusscript, xpages-ssjs

This is a rather generic question, but I'll try to be as precise as possible:

quite often I'm asked by customers for proper implementations of LotusScript's

```
continue = false
```

in Notes' *Query** events. One quite common situation is a form's *QueryOpen* event where we actually can stop the process of opening the document in question based on some condition, e.g based on the response from a user dialog.

For some Xpages events like *querySaveDocument* there are quite obvious solutions, whereas with others I only can recommend re-thinking the entire logic like preventing code execution at a much earlier stage. But of course most people in question would prefer a generic approach like "re-write those codes using...". And - to be honest - I'd like to know myself ;)

I'm more or less familiar with the Xpages / JSF lifecycle, but have to admit that I don't have a proper idea how I could stop execution at any given phase.
As always, any hint is welcome.

*EDIT* (to clarify my question, but also in response to Tim's answer below):

It's not just the QuerySave but also the QueryModeChange and QueryRecalc that somehow need to be transformed together ith an existng application's logic but that don't have their equivalent in the Xpages logic. Are both concepts (forms based and xpages based) just too different at this point?

As an example think of a workflow application where we need to check certain conditions before we allow opening an existing doc in *edit mode* for a potential author. In my Notes client application I add some code to 2 events, i.e. *QueryOpen*, where I check the "*mode*" arg, and 2nd *QueryModeChange*, where I check the *current doc mode*. In both cases I can prevent the doc from being edited by adding my `continue = false`, if necessary. Depending on the event the doc will either not change its mode, or not open at all.

With an Xpage I can use buttons for changing a doc's edit mode, and I can "hide" those buttons, or just add some checking code or whatever.
But 17 years of Domino consulting have tought me at least one lesson: there'll always be users that'll find the hidden ways to reach their goals. In our case they might find out that a simple modification of the page's URL will finally allow them to edit the doc. To prevent this I could maybe use the "*beforeRenderResponse*" event, I assume. But then, *beforeRenderResponse* is also called in  other situations as well, so that we have to investigate the current situation first. Or I could make sure that users don't have author rights unless the situation allows it.

Again, not a huge problem, but when making the transition from a legacy Notes application this means re-thinking its entire logic. Which makes the job more tediuos, and especilly more expensive.

True? Or am I missing some crucial parts of the concept?

Comment: You should always use *ignoreRequestParameters* for your data sources and compute the parameters by yourself. This prevents security problems and allows to handle errors (DicUnid not existing etc) by yourself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Structure your events as action groups and, when applicable, return `false`. This will cause all remaining actions in the group to be skipped.

For example, you could split a "Save" button into two separate actions:

1.

```
// by default, execute additional actions:
var result = true;
/* execute some logic here */
if (somethingFailed) {
    result = false;
}
return result;
```

Replace `somethingFailed` with an evaluation based on whatever logic you have in place of the block comment to determine whether it's appropriate to now save the document.

2.

```
return currentDocument.save();
```

Not only does the above pattern cause the call to `save()` to be skipped if the first action returns `false`, but because `save()`, in turn, returns a boolean, you could theoretically also add a third action as a kind of `postSave` event: if the save is successful, the third action will automatically run; if the save fails, the third action will be automatically skipped.

All `queryModeChange` logic should be moved to the `readonly` attribute of a panel (or the `view` root of an XPage or Custom Control) containing all otherwise editable content... you would basically just be flipping the boolean: traditionally, `queryModeChange` would treat `false` (for `Continue`) as an indication that the document should not be edited (although this also forces you to check whether the user is trying to change from read to edit, because if you forgo this check, you're potentially also preventing a user from changing the mode back to read when it's already in edit), whereas `readonly` should of course return `true` if the content should not be editable.

Since the `queryModeChange` approach was nearly always an additional layer of "fig leaf" security, in XPages it's far better to handle this via actual security mechanisms; the `readonly` attribute is explicitly intended for enforcing security. Additionally, in lieu of using `readonly`, you could instead use the `acl` complex property that is also available for panels, XPages, and Custom Controls to provide different permissions to different subsets of users; anyone with a certain role, for instance, would automatically have edit, whereas the level for the default entry can be computed based on item values indicating the current "status" and/or "assignee". With either (or both) of these mechanisms in place, it doesn't matter what the user does to the URL... the relevant components *cannot* be editable if the container is read only. They could even try to hack in by running JavaScript in Chrome Developer Tools, attempting to emulate the POST requests that would be sent if they *could* edit the content... the data they send will still not get pushed back to the model, because the targeted components are read-only by virtue of the attributes of their container.

Attempting to apply all Notes client patterns directly to the XPages context is nearly always an exercise in frustration -- and, ultimately, futility. While I won't divulge specifics here, I (and some of the smartest people I know) learned this lesson at great cost. While users may say (and even believe) that they want exactly what they already have... if they did, they would be keeping what they already have, not paying you to turn it into something else. So any migration from a Notes client app to an XPage "equivalent" is your one opportunity to revisit the *reason* the code used to do what it did, and determine whether that even makes sense to retain within the XPage, based not only on the differential between Notes client and XPage paradigms, but also on any differential between what the users' business process was when the Notes client app was developed and what their process is *now*. 
Omitting this evaluation guarantees that the resulting app will be running code it doesn't need to and fail to make the most of the target platform.

`queryRecalc` is a perfect example of this: typically, recalculation was blocked to optimize performance when the user's desktop and network resources were responsible for performing complex and/or network-intensive recalculations. In XPages this all happens on the server, so a network request from the browser that returns a page where everything has changed is typically no more expensive for the end user than a page where nothing has changed (unless there's an extreme differential in the amount of markup that is actually sent). Unless the constituent components are bound to data that is expensive for the *server* to recalculate, logical blocking of recalculation offers little or no performance benefit for the user. Furthermore, if you're trying to block recalculation in an event, you're too late: XPages uses a "lifecycle" that consists of 6 phases, so by the time your event code runs, any recalculation you're trying to block has already occurred. So, if the reason for blocking recalculation was to optimize performance, implement a scope caching strategy that ensures you're only pulling fresh data when it makes sense to do so, and the end user experience will be sufficiently performant without trying to prevent the entire page from recalculating. If, on the other hand, `queryRecalc` was being used as another fig leaf (something *has* changed, but we don't *want* to show the user the updates yet), that logic should **definitely** be revisited to determine whether it's still applicable, still (if ever) a good idea, and which portions of the platform are now the best fit for meeting the business process objectives.

In summary, use the security mechanisms unique to XPages for locking down portions or all of a page, and use the memory scopes that we didn't have in the Notes client to ensure the application performs well. Porting an event that used to contain this logic to an XPage event that continues to contain this logic will likely fail to produce the desired result and squander some of the benefits of migrating to XPages.

Comment: Many thanks, as always; sounds like a good approach. I'm in the habit of preferring "real" SSJS code instead of using those dreaded "simple actions". Most probably I should get over this... - But please have look back at my original question as I added some more details to it

Comment: Lothar,
an action group can very well contain "the real thing" - check it out!

Comment: @Tim: once more many thanks for yet another great answer. This will also make a fine list of arguments when discussion transition plans with customers

Comment: @stwissel: I know, I know. It's more like a bad habit I'll have to overcome, really...